# Cannot access elements in iframe

Tags: selenium, webdriver, c#

I cannot access elements inside of an iframe, I have tried the call:

```
IWebElement iframeSwitch = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//iframe[contains(@id, 'contentIFrame1')and contains (@title, 'Content Area')]"));
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(iframeSwitch);
driver.FindElement(By.Id("hlx_markertemplateid_ledit")).SendKeys("Test");
```

This is a sample of the HTML for the Table

```
<table id="hlx_markertemplateid_lookupTable" class="ms-crm-Lookup" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" lookupid="hlx_markertemplateid" style="width: 100%; table-layout: fixed;" aria-labelledby="hlx_markertemplateid_c hlx_markertemplateid_w" controlmode="normal">
```

This is a sample of the td

```
<td valign="top">
 <div id="hlx_markertemplateid_lookupDiv" class="ms-crm-Lookup ms-crm-InlineLookupEdit ms-crm-Hidden-NoBehavior" role="list" ime-mode="auto" tabindex="0" style="width: 0px;">
  <ul class="ms-crm-InlineLookupEdit"></ul>
</div>
 <label class="ms-crm-Hidden-NoBehavior" for="hlx_markertemplateid_ledit">Marker Template Required</label>
 <input id="hlx_markertemplateid_ledit" class="ms-crm-InlineInput ms-crm-InlineLookupEdit" type="text" ime-mode="auto" maxlength="1000" style="ime-mode: auto;">
</td>
```

It seems like the iframe switch is successful(because there are no errors for that call) but I cannot access any of the content on the iframe. Thanks for your suggestions ahead of time.

Comment: You get the standard element not found for id hlx_markertemplateid_ledit?

Comment: are you getting any exception?

Comment: Element not found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could send the text "Test" to the input text box inside iFrame. I used findById . Code is in Java but you can modify accordingly for C#.

```
WebElement iframeSwitch = driver.findElement(By.id("contentIFrame1"));
driver.switchTo().frame(iframeSwitch);
System.out.println("Switched");
driver.findElement(By.id("hlx_markertemplateid_ledit")).sendKeys("Test");
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar issue, so used the following approach:

```
actionObject = new Actions(firefoxDrvrInstance); 
actionObject.MoveToElement(find element here).Perform(); 
firefoxDrvrInstance.FindElement(blah blah).Click(); 
firefoxDrvrInstance.SwitchTo().Frame(firefoxDrvrInstance.FindElement(blah blah));
```

let me know if anything is not clear here...

This code is in C#.